# Magento 1.8 How to add comments to ship emails

Tags: magento-1.8, shipping, template, email

I'm trying to add comments to the ship email I sent, but the checkbox "Append Comments" is disabled. 
Does anyone know why this is happening?

Answer (score 2):

In order to be able to check the "Append Comments" you need to check the "Email Copy of Shipment" checkbox right below the "Append Comments" checkbox.

If you don't have the "Email Copy of Shipment" checkbox it means it is disabled from the system->configuration section.

You can enable it from `System->Configuration->Sales Emails->Shipment->Enabled`

Comment: Thanks, but that option is already enabled. I'm using a custom template and maybe it's because of that? How can I had a comment block to my custom email?

Comment: Try reverting to the default template. Or compare the differences between the default template and yours.

Comment: the default template is not sending comments either... I noticed that only the online credit memo email template sends the comments.

Answer (score 1):

I needed to add the following to the template:

```
{{var comment}}
```